# .Net core configuration provider for AKS Kubernetes CSI Driver for secrets from Azure Key Vault

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, configuration, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

we successfully configured the [CSI Driver for Azure Kubernetes Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-integrate-kubernetes).  This allows us to pull in secrets from Azure Key Vault as "files" in our Pods (in our AKS Kubernetes cluster).  The **name** of the file is the name of the secret.  The **contents** of the file is the value of the secret.  I can of course read these files to get the secrets.  But I am wondering if there is some kind of IConfigurationProvider/IConfigurationSource.... already implemented that allows me to access these secrets using the standard .Net core IConfiguration object. That would allow me to do something like :

```
builder.AddSecretsFromCSI(someRootPathForTheFiles);
```

in the program.cs file.  Just avoiding that I have to write this myself.  (I don't want to use the keyvault provider inside my .net core code to avoid that dependency inside my code - files work everywhere)

Answer (score 6):

It turns out .Net core has exactly what is needed for this (although a little underdocumented IMHO) :

```
config.AddKeyPerFile("/app/secrets", optional: true);
```

(see also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#key-per-file-configuration-provider)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 or 3 different ways to integrate KayVault...
Using CSI Driver in AKS is a great way to let your application agnostic relative to configuration provider. You can, for example, put this secrets mounted as volume then into env variables inside POD. Then code your app to load all env variables into AspNet standard configuration, then all your KeyVault will be ready to be consumed using the interface IConfiguration["my-keyVault-key"]
Another way is to use the Azure extension package. You add into your Program.cs an Azure SDK extension that injects all keyVault keys and secrets into standard IConfiguration interface. Consume it using IConfiguration["my-secret-or-key"]

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing but that was not really the question.  The question was specifically about the CSI driver.  For the record, we abandoned that approach and went for managed identities which solves our KeyVault problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32922775)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).